# ANR warning onMeasure time too long

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Whenever I run the code I get this warning

> D/View: [ANR Warning]onMeasure time too long.

I have no idea of what it is trying to say to me and because this the layout takes a much more time to render.

I have tried re-arranging the layout but no help

> D/View: [ANR Warning]onMeasure time too long, this
>   =com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigationViewPager{19f6e66
>   VFED..... ......time
>   =412 ms

Can anyone please help me out?